# Flowtype not responding to window.resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a plugin called flowtype (http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) and its not responding to a window.resize event that I have triggered for browser resizing. I am using css media queries to change the width of elements which effects the size of the flowtype font values, so I am trying to implement a javascript media query to change the flowtype values of those elements and keep everything looking nice.

Here's the javascript:

```
function fontSize() {
    $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if($windowWidth < 700) {
        alert('resize detected: ' + $windowWidth);
        $('.mobile-message').flowtype({ fontRatio : 20 });
        $('.header-link').flowtype({ fontRatio : 10 });
        $('.social-link').flowtype({ fontRatio : 2 });
        $('footer div').flowtype({ fontRatio : 40 });
    } else {
        alert('resize detected: ' + $windowWidth);
        $('.header-link').flowtype({ fontRatio : 14 });
        $('.social-link').flowtype({ fontRatio : 5.5 });
        $('footer div').flowtype({ fontRatio : 70 });
    }
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
    fontSize();
});
```

I think that its not reading the screen size as it changes fast enough, I'm pretty sure its assigning the less than 700px flowtype values to when its greater than 700px and the greater than 700px values to when its less than 700px.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "not responding"? What do you want it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: By not responding I mean what I said after I posted the code, I think it isn't actually responding to the screen size - its like its a step behind.

Comment: And adding a console.log() in there to see if it's firing, and the value of $windowWidth gives you...?

Comment: In my case 638 and 1903, I'm pressing the full screen icon in the top right next to the x. It works fine if you're just dragging it.

Comment: So if you hit "full screen" it's not firing a resize event? That's odd.

Comment: I think it is, its giving me the values of the screen size - its just not translating into the changing flowtypes. Like if I have the screen open at full size and I resize it down it keeps the original font size, once I maximize the screen it switches to the mobile fontsize, I resize it back down and it switches to the full screen fontsizes. Its like a step behind.